# How to build model from text file with no headers but having specific format

Tags: c#, model, text-files, system.reflection, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a text file with specific format. I want to read that text file and create model from it or bind some existing model to it.

```
1  AL300 SAMPLE
2  Station 1001
3 
4  SampleGrade
5  PROP-SUMMARY
6  5213
7  True
8  Burst C BS ( 181)
9  PROP-VALUES
10 Front
11 22.001
12 1
13 PROP-VALUES
14 Middle
15 22.0
16 3
17 PROP-SUMMARY
18 5213
19 0
20 Burst C BS ( 181)
21 PROP-VALUES
22 Middle
23 22.0
24 3
25 end AL300 SAMPLE
```

1. First line is header text and should not be part of model.
2. Last line specifies end of file and should not be part of model.
3. Line numbers are for understanding purpose only. Original text file
   will not have it.
4. Line 2,3,4 is one set of data and line 2 is empty(tab or carriage
   return).
5. Line 5(PROP-SUMMARY) till line 16 is another set of data which
   contains its own data(line 6,7,8) and list of PROP-VALUES(Line 9 and
   Line 17). Line 10,11,12 and 14,15,16 are data for PROP-VALUES.

Now I want to generate model based on this. I am planning to build model something like this

```
public class SampleExportDto
{
    public SampleDetailsExportDto Sample { get; set; }
    public List<SummaryDto> Summary { get; set; }
}
public class SampleDetailsExportDto //SummaryDto
{
    public int    Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
}

public class SummaryDto
{
    public int    Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public List<ValuesDto> Values { get; set; }
}

public class ValuesDto
{
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help me in achieving this assuming each row has some column name which will be mapped to model in the given DTO(Data Transfer Object)

Comment: You'd need to create a custom formatter. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for the link. I have checked the link but not getting clear idea of which formatter to use. However I have created Custom Output formatter. But now not sure how to use it. I have input text file to be read and need to assign it model, am I doing correct thing?

Comment: All of that is covered in the docs I linked. You add your custom formatter to the input and/or output formatters in the call to `AddMvc`. Once that's done, then you don't need to do anything else. You just bind to a class as if you were accepting JSON, and when the request body has the mime type that your custom formatter is associated with, it will use that custom formatter to deserialize into the class.